# How can I get the body of an HTTP response using LWP::UserAgent in Perl?

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I find that the return from `LWP::UserAgent->request()` contains both the header and body of a HTTP response. I just need the body of the response to do some parsing, so how can I
do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
require LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $response = $ua->get('http://search.cpan.org/');

if ($response->is_success) {

    print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

`response->decoded_content` will return the body of the response.

Answer (score 6):

The `request` method ([according to the manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::UserAgent)) returns an [HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Response) object, which has a `content` method. Just call that.

```
$ua->request->content;
```

Comment: You might actually want `decoded_content`, which deals with text encodings (in HTTP/MIME lingo, charsets) as well as HTTP `Content-Encoding`s like gzip.